# Цветные линии в зависимости от значений

Tags: delphi, диаграммы

```
var  
str,s,s2:string;  
i:integer;  
t:TTime;  
heh, hah: real;  
begin  
  series2.Clear;  
  str:=label12.Caption;  
  for i:=0 to listBox2.Count-1 do  
  begin  
    s:=floattostr(StrToFloat(listBox2.Items[i])-StrToFloat(str));  
    s2:= listBox3.Items[i];  
    Delete(s2, 9, 4);  
    t:=StrToTime(s2);  
    hah:=strtofloat(listBox2.Items[i] );  
    heh:=t  ;  
      if abs(strtofloat(s))<=strtofloat( edit3.Text) then Series2.addXY(heh,hah,'', clGreen) else  
      if (abs(strtofloat(s))>strtofloat( edit3.Text)) and (abs(strtofloat(s)<=strtofloat( edit4.Text)) then Series2.addXY(heh,hah,'', clYellow) else  
      if abs(strtofloat(s))>strtofloat( edit4.Text) then Series2.addXY(heh,hah,'', clred)  
  end;  
end;
```

Есть такой код, его идея в том, чтоб в зависимости от величины разницы значения от среднего значения рисовать график разными цветами. 
Но у меня выдается ошибка

> "0.0001"is not a valid floating point value

0.0001 - это первая граница, с чем должно сравниваться. У меня вопрос: почему выдаёт такую ошибку?

**Добавлено.**

Чтобы точно получать нужные цвета, добавил еще 3 серии, в которых заранее заданы цвета. Вроде цветовая градация получилась, но не так, как хотелось. Из-за того, что теперь график разбивается на 3 отдельных графика, между зонами появился разрыв, а если 2 блока одного цвета разделены расстоянием, то их соединяет прямая, что выглядит не очень эстетично. В принципе работает, но не так, как хотелось бы чтобы это была одна непрерывная прямая, но с участками разного цвета.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Потому что в настройках ОС разделитель дробной части запятая, а не точка. Либо пишите число с запятой, либо меняйте настройки ОС.

Comment: Точно, спс.  
Вечно путаю.  
Тогда еще такой вопрос по коду: все меняет цвета, а у меня все черное, как было так и осталось.

Нет вариантов, как еще сделать что б график был разных цветов?